# How to take the MAX of a column and subtract it from all values in that same column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql

Here's the table:

| PersonID | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 30 |
| 3 | 40 |

I'm trying to take the max of "amount", which is 40 and subtract it from all values from the same column so that it looks like this

| PersonID | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 (40-(10+10) |
| 2 | 10 (40-30) |
| 3 | 0 (40-50) |

```
SELECT 
    PersonID, MAX(Price) - Price
FROM
    (SELECT 
         PersonID, SUM(amount) AS Price
     FROM sales
     GROUP BY PersonID) Alias1
GROUP BY 
    PersonID
```

The problem is that I get an error when running this query:

> Column 'Alias1.Price' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of SQL support analytic functions, then use `MAX()` that way:

```sql
SELECT PersonID, MAX(SUM(amount)) OVER () - SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM sales
GROUP BY PersonID;
```

### Demo

Here is an approach which does not use analytic functions:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT PersonID, SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY PersonID
)

SELECT PersonID, (SELECT MAX(amount) FROM cte) - amount AS amount
FROM cte;
```